# MFMailComposeViewController for iOS 5: Tutorial or Example

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Does anyone have a decent tutorial on how to implement mail composer for ios 5 either programmatically or with segues? Most of the tutorials that I found online are from old iOS versions. Thanks!

Comment: The implementation hasn't changed much if at all. It's just creating the view controller and calling it modally in the easiest cases. Basically like you would push a controller modally without using iOS storyboards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Mail Subject!"];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"Here is your message body" isHTML:NO];
    [mailController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"yourrecipent@domain.com"]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 1.0f);
    if(imageData.length)
    {
        [mailController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Your_Photo.jpg"];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Image" message:@"The image couldn't be converted." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
else NSLog(@"Hah. No mail for you.");
```

Comment: before do this stuff you must check [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] otherwise you get crash in case of mail not set up

Answer (score 2):

At first you have to add "MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate" to interface section.

Also you have to add procedure to get response after user taps "Send button"

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"You sent the email.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"You saved a draft of this email");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"You cancelled sending this email.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed:  An error occurred when trying to compose this email");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"An error occurred when trying to compose this email");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```